# Angular : Is there a way to identify html form controls uniquely inside ts component?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Typescript Method

```
 addOneDocument(supplierForm){
    const controls = supplierForm.controls;
    for(const name in controls){

      if (controls[name].invalid) {
        controls[name].touched=true;
    }
    }
  }
```

I want to change this method to check a particular form control for errors.
I actually want something like following

```
 if ((controls[name].invalid)&&(controls[name].name=="document"))
```

but name property doesn't exist on type FormControl. How to identify a particular html form control uniquely in typescript?

Answer (score 0):

You could think of form controls as a tree-like structure. For example, the parent would be  a `FormGroup`and its descendants could be some `FormControls`/`FormGroups`/`FormArrays` and so on.

I'm not aware of any way to identify a form control like this, but the best solution that comes to mind it to use the `get()` method, to which you can provide a **path** to your form control.

Excerpt from [A thorough exploration of Angular Forms](https://indepth.dev/a-thorough-exploration-of-angular-forms/#retrieving-abstractcontrols-from-the-tree)
:

```js
const fg = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl(''),
  address: new FormGroup({
    city: new FormControl(''),
    street: new FormControl(''),
  }),
});
```

You could use the `get` method like this:

```js
fg.get('address.city')

// Or

fg.get(['address', 'street'])
```

So, I'd say that a way to identify a form control would be to use its **path**.